# Bad access crash while decoding a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have received 2 crash report from where the back traces seems to suggest there is a problem decoding images references in a storyboard.  It was reported on this device

[image]

I cant reproduce it on my iPhone 5 running 7.1  nor in the simulator running 7.0.  I am using the 7.1 SDK, storyboards and asset catalogs.

The first log looks like this:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x9000000c

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib  0x39c9ab66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreGraphics     0x2f9bbc09 CGImageRetain + 16
2  UIKit            0x320d742b -[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] + 114
3  UIKit            0x320d739f +[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] + 62
4  UIKit            0x320e2c4b -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:] + 334
5  UIKit            0x320e2af7 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:] + 38
6  UIKit            0x320e2acd -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:subtype:] + 44
...
```

The second is slightly different:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib  0x39c9ab66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreUI           0x33a7bd0d -[CUIStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:] + 1052
2  CoreUI           0x33a850af -[CUINamedImage _renditionForSpecificKey:] + 170
3  CoreUI           0x33a850fd -[CUINamedImage image] + 20
4  UIKit            0x320e2c01 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:] + 260
5  UIKit            0x320e2af7 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:] + 38
6  UIKit            0x320e2acd -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:subtype:] + 44
```

The rest of the trace from lines 6 onwards is common to both crash logs.

```
7  UIKit            0x320e2a9b -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:] + 46
8  UIKit            0x32427ab1 -[UIImageNibPlaceholder initWithCoder:] + 288
9  UIKit            0x324bd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 740
10 UIKit            0x324bceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90
11 UIKit            0x3241b4bd -[UIButtonContent initWithCoder:] + 296
12 UIKit            0x324bd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 740
13 UIKit            0x324bd557 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1634
14 UIKit            0x324bceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90
15 UIKit            0x3241d613 -[UIButton initWithCoder:] + 594
16 UIKit            0x324bd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 740
17 UIKit            0x324bceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90
18 UIKit            0x32426bf9 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 112
19 UIKit            0x3242723f -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 42
20 UIKit            0x324bd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 740
21 UIKit            0x324bd179 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 644
22 UIKit            0x324bceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 90
23 UIKit            0x324263f5 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 888
24 UIKit            0x323880fb -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 234
25 UIKit            0x321e9b59 -[UIViewController loadView] + 92
26 UIKit            0x320cb79d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 72
27 UIKit            0x320cb719 -[UIViewController view] + 24
28 UIKit            0x321412a3 -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 58
29 UIKit            0x32141209 -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 76
30 UIKit            0x321b0fb5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 4604
31 UIKit            0x321af631 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4676
32 FaceInvaders     0x0000e885 -[RSHomeViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (RSHomeViewController.m:93)
33 UIKit            0x321e40cb -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1078
34 UIKit            0x32297863 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 214
35 UIKit            0x32147781 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
36 UIKit            0x320bf7bb _afterCACommitHandler + 430
37 CoreFoundation   0x2f90df69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
38 CoreFoundation   0x2f90b8f7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 286
39 CoreFoundation   0x2f90bc43 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
40 CoreFoundation   0x2f876471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
41 CoreFoundation   0x2f876253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
42 GraphicsServices 0x345b02eb GSEventRunModal + 138
43 UIKit            0x3212b845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
44 FaceInvaders     0x00017fa1 main (main.m:16)
```

Any ideas what might be causing this or just how I could debug it?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the issue, the storyboard contained this markup:

```
<image name="pressed" width="1" height="1"/>
```

Whereas the actual image was 1x80 pixels.

Presumably certain versions of iOS trust the storyboard and allocate a buffer of incorrect size whereas other versions do some sort of bounds checking.

So solution is to check the `<resources>` tag, at the end of the storybaord's XML, for incorrect sizes.  If there are any, remove the images and add them again.  If this doesn't work, remove the image entirely and just load it in code instead.